# How to define flow type for object literals defined inside an array

Tags: javascript, flowtype

My code is:

```
type Column = {
    columnName: string,
    columnSize: number
}

...

export const columns: Column[] = [
{
    'columnName': '1',
    'columnSize': 3
},
{
    'columnName': 2',
    'columnSize': 4
}
]
```

But I'm receiving `Error: array literal has some incompatible type argument with Array<Column>. Array type is incompatible with object literal.`

So I guess my question is how do you add type definitions for object literals defined within an array?

This is for flow `0.61.0` which is unfortunately locked in place.

Comment: You're missing a quote in the second `columnName`. Does the real code have both quotes, or neither quote?

Comment: Not reproducible https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AYVtAK4C2AdqALygDeio9oAxgSaQHICGxWAXKAM4oATgEtSAcwA0dBsyJkAyiIBevUKRIAjLEMQBfZM1KCmLMvz755pANoBdSqBuJaDUAHI5rTt3d93AIzu0m6eZqRKqn6gAMz60q4MYdY+WNHuAEzBMvTJrJFpfAAs+oh2QA

Comment: Great points here Aleksey I'll try to come up with a better working code snippet.